# raised ... 25 basis points or raised ... by 25 basis points?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if it is correct to add the word "by" in the following sentence:  Today, bank x raised its loan rate by 25 basis points.

Comment: I suppose the "by" is implied if you don't write it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting example, and to be honest I think it shows the weakness of many dictionaries. The verb "raise" is listed in most dictionaries as transitive, however, that is rather a simplification of the truth. A more correct measure of a verb's argument count would be its [valency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29).

Verbs in English can be monovalent, when they take only a subject, divalent when they take a subject and an object, and trivalent when they take a subject and two objects. The verb "to read" can be all three. For example:

```
He reads.
He reads a book.
He reads her a book.
```

Obviously these are monovalent, divalent and trivalent respectively.
In the case of "raise" it seems that it can be both divalent and trivalent. If we say:

```
The bank raised interest rates by 25 basis points.
```

We are using it as a divalent verb with a prepositional phrase (*by 25 basis points*.)

If we say:

```
The bank raised interest rates 25 basis points.
```

We are using it as a trivalent verb with two objects, "interest rates" and "25 basis points."

I think this trivalent approach is uncommon, and I suspect it is more common in the American English dialect, but it is not unique to this construction. For example:

```
My promotion means they raise my salary $10,000.
```

Would also be acceptable, and a trivalent usage of this verb.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the word "by" sounds more correct to me. Without it, the sentence seems like it is missing something in the spot where the word "by" would have been.